# Suitelet redirect to record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a suitelet script that creates a csv format file from the line-items of Opportunity. on Opportunity created a 'Export CSV' button which calls this suitelet.

```
var fileObj = file.create({
                    name: 'transactions.csv',
                    fileType: file.Type.CSV,
                    contents: data,
                    description: 'This is transactions',
                    folder: 13497862
                });
                var Fileid = fileObj.save();
                var loadFile = file.load({ id: Fileid });
                var fileurl = loadFile.url;
                var html = "";
                html += "<html>";
                html += "<script>";
                html += 'window.location.href="' + fileurl + '";\n';
                html += "</script>";
                html += "</html>";
                response.write(html);
```

After response.write executes, the file gets downloaded in computer. but after that I want it to redirect again to the Opportunity. But its returning a blank screen.

I used `redirect.toRecord()` but it is not executing because `response.write(html)` executes first and script stops there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try forcing the browser to download the file and then redirect to the opportunity record.

```
var html = '';
html += '<html>'
            '<script>' +
                'var a = document.createElement('a');' +
                'a.href = "' + fileurl + '";' +
                'a.download = "' + fileurl + '";'
                'document.body.appendChild(a);' +
                'a.click();'; +
                'setTimeout(function(){' +
                '    window.location.href = "REDIRECT_URL";' +
                '}, 5000);' +
             '</script>' +
        '</html>';

response.write(html);
```

However, this solution may not always bring the exact same results on all browsers. A client script could be more appropriate for your requirement.